# Custom Login with Encrypted Password joomla

Tags: php, encryption, joomla, md5, joomla3.0

I want to create a custom script in which a user gets automatically logged in if some special URL is hit. My problem is that I am unable to login with encrypted password.

```
$username = 'prabhash76';
$password = '$2y$10$nIFUs.Nd6dagGL.3kbPsr.uPL/8kDns6Li8ac7rOpDCz4njynXkPO'; //encrypted password
$result = JFactory::getApplication()->login(array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$password), array('remember' => true));
```

This is script I am using but problem in that is that it uses password as a plain text - but I want to login using the encrypted password.

---

([crossposted](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=941872&p=3447900#p3447900) at *The Joomla! Forum*)

Answer (score 0):

if you want login with encrypted password , you have to write Authentication plugin for encrypted password. otherwise you can't login.